# Accuracy of ArcGIS Collector

Tags: gps, accuracy, arcgis-collector

About ArcGIS Collector app, what's the difference between accuracy in the setting tab and horizontal/vertical accuracy as indicated left-bottom on the map while surveying?

For example, if I set the accuracy at 10cm with 95% in the setting menu, but I got 7.5m horizontal, 11.4m vertical accuracy when measuring a point. I don't know the different between them

Comment: Please can we have only 1 question.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. As a new user, please take the [Tour], which emphasizes the importance of asking One question per Question. This assures that all Answers address all questions in the Question, and that answers can be judged on a even basis.

Comment: Sorry, I changed the question

Comment: You still have three questions marked in your question.